# SELECT NEXT ROW, COMPARE, SET PREVIOUS ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

So I have a history table called `Member_Phys_History` in SQL-Server 2008

Looks like this:

```
RecID, MemberID, Phys_ID, Phys_Start, Phys_End, Phys_Update
```

The first column is `identity`, the `Phys_Start`, `Phys_End`, and `Phys_Update` are dates.

I have another table called `Member_Phys_Update`

```
MemberID, Phys_ID, Phys_Start_Date
```

So once a week or so this Update table get's an update from client where The Phys_ID changes and the Phys_start is later in time...So I add this information to my History table and it would look like this:

```
1|ABC123|555|2014-01-01|NULL|NULL
2|ABC123|556|2014-04-01|NULL|NULL
```

**Here's what I need to do:**

I want to basically set the first records Phys_End_Date to the day before the second records `Phys_Start_Date`. So it would look like this:

```
1|ABC123|555|2014-01-01|2014-03-30|NULL
2|ABC123|556|2014-04-01|NULL|NULL
```

I cannot use a stored procedure with a cursor unfortunately, my DBA says it's inefficient. I was wondering if there was any way I could do this in a couple queries...

A cursor may be ideal, but can I do this with a FETCH NEXT or something?

Comment: Is the table updated through a stored proc?

Comment: No, through a manual INSERT INTO statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Select A.*, B.Phys_End_Date
from table1 A
outer apply (select (min(Phys_Start_Date) - 1) Phys_End_Date from table1 x
             where x.Phys_Start_Date > A.Phys_Start_Date
             AND X.MemberID = A.MemberID) B
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2c7d3/1)

Edit (Adding Update SQL)

```
update A
set A.Phys_End_Date = B.Phys_End_Date
from table1 A     
outer apply (select (min(Phys_Start_Date) - 1) Phys_End_Date from table1 x
             where x.Phys_Start_Date > A.Phys_Start_Date
             AND X.MemberID = A.MemberID) B

or

INSERT INTO table2 (memberid, phys_id,Phys_Start_Date,Phys_End_Date)
Select A.*, B.Phys_End_Date
from table1 A
outer apply (select (min(Phys_Start_Date) - 1) Phys_End_Date from table1 x
             where x.Phys_Start_Date > A.Phys_Start_Date
             AND X.MemberID = A.MemberID) B;
```

Comment: but actually, I need to update table1..I'm going to just change the t2 table to table1

Comment: What is the difference between this and cross apply? Why did you choose outer apply? and would I notice anything significant if I changed it to cross apply? I am testing now and I can't see any difference...

Comment: outer apply will return all the rows from left even when there is no match from right table, CROSS APPLY will return rows from left table only if they match expression in the right table( like INNER JOIN)

Comment: so my second table is returning the "next" row's value. i'm looking at my WHERE clause, because when the rows are affected it affects the entire result set which could be misleading if anyone runs this besides me. Is there someway I can return just the affected rows, as a count?

Answer (score 2):

As alternative you can do it using Common Table expression.

```
;WITH   base
          AS (
               SELECT *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY Phys_Start ASC ) AS rn
                FROM Member_Phys_History 
             ),
        nextDate
          AS (
               SELECT *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY Phys_Start ASC ) AS rn
                FROM Member_Phys_History 
             )
    SELECT b.RecID
           ,b.MemberID
           ,b.Phys_ID
           ,b.Phys_Start
           ,DATEADD(dd, -1, n.Phys_Start) AS Phy_End
           ,b.Phys_Update
        FROM base AS b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN nextDate AS n
            ON b.MemberID = n.MemberID
               AND b.rn = n.rn - 1;
```

Than it is really easy to turn it into `UPDATE` statement

```
;WITH   base
          AS (
               SELECT *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY Phys_Start ASC ) AS rn
                FROM Member_Phys_History 
             ),
        nextDate
          AS (
               SELECT *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY Phys_Start ASC ) AS rn
                FROM Member_Phys_History 
             )
    UPDATE b
        SET b.Phys_End = DATEADD(dd, -1, n.Phys_Start)
        FROM base AS b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN nextDate AS n
            ON b.MemberID = n.MemberID
               AND b.rn = n.rn - 1;
```

Comment: I was looking into this way as well, let me try this

Answer (score 0):

**SQL fiddles -**

You will not see all columns of select here. Run it in your sql server.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75dca/2

**Limitation -** My code works only when Phys_ID (your table) or Code (my table) are consecutive numbers.

**Another way do the self join -**

```
select *
from tblz as t1
inner join tblz as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and (t1.code = t2.code - 1)
```

**Update using the above query -**

```
update t1
set t1.EndDate = Dateadd(DAY, -1, t2.StartDate)
--select *
from tblz as t1
inner join tblz as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and (t1.code = t2.code - 1)
```